# How to Convert a 14 Digit number to a DateTime in (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, datetime, time

Well the question is:

I have these 2 columns, 1 stores the day in a number format and the other stores the hour also in a number format like so:

```
ID_DAY      ||      ID_HOUR

20130912    ||      104237       = 2013/09/12 10:42:37

20130912    ||      105145       = 2013/09/12 10:51:45

20130912    ||      105211       = 2013/09/12 10:52:11
```

My goal is to calculate the difference between the datetimes, like so:

```
From 2013/09/12 10:42:37 to 2013/09/12 10:51:45

passed: 00:09:34  (example in HH24:MM:SS)
```

Any help from you guys would be great!

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yeah, this is why datetimes should be stored using an appropriate data type. Any chance of changing it?

Comment: Well actually these are 2 foreign keys that will join 2 time dimensions 1 for days and so on... and the other for hours... i prefer to join with a number datatype than a datetime or i will have performance issues in the future, plus with those 2 dimensions i wont have to calculate nothing because they will give all the details like year work day and so on.. but thanks for your input!

Comment: "... join with a number datatype than a datetime or i will have performance issues in the future" -- well that's rather controversial. Also, you don't usually calculate year, work day etc in a date dimension, you just provide columns with the values in them. Your choice, though.

Comment: Thanks for your input again. I mentioned that "i wont have to calculate nothing because they will give all the details" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to convert to dates (I have included the statements I used to create the data etc.):

**UPDATE - adjusted to reflect number datatype**

```
drop table some_table;
create table some_table (ID_DAY number(8), ID_HOUR number(6));
insert into some_table values (20130912, 0);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 1);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 94511);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 104237);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 105145);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 105211);
commit;

select t.id_day, t.id_hour,
       to_date(t.id_day||lpad(t.id_hour, 6, 0), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') date_value
  from some_table t;
```

This gives you a query with date data types and appears to have done the right thing with the hours before 1am.

```
Id Day    Id Hour  Date Value 
------    -------  ----------
20130912  0        12/09/2013 
20130912  1        12/09/2013 00:00:01 
20130912  94511    12/09/2013 09:45:11 
20130912  104237   12/09/2013 10:42:37 
20130912  105145   12/09/2013 10:51:45 
20130912  105211   12/09/2013 10:52:11
```

Comment: Thanks you very much for you reply. I was analyzing it and there is a small detail, imagine that the ID_HOUR is 1 or 0, 1 actually means 00:00:01 and zero means 00:00:00 so every time i will have these IDs it wont work :(

Comment: @SenSer No problem, just read your question again and noticed the number format comment. Above I have used varchar2. On the whole the conversions should be the same (for the examples you gave), but I am just thinking out how it would handle cases before 10am i.e. whether it has less digits then. Please confirm.

Comment: I am trying my best to avoid creating a view or a table. I though initially like CONCAT those 2 columns and use the numbers like you did, instead of creating a view

Comment: No problem, the view was just for testing so that you can then have a go at the operations you want to without having to re-create the new format each time. Regarding the number/varchar2 issue, I have tested it both ways and it seems to work even when the time number is only 5 digits (i.e. before 10am).

Comment: Well something is strange because ORA is saying this: ORA-01850: a hora deve situar-se entre 0 e 23
01850. 00000 -  "hour must be between 0 and 23"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: Okay, I have made adjustments to use the source data type as number. I have just included an lpad to fill the field out with zeros where needed.

Comment: Man that's perfect! Thank you very much it really helped!! It's so nice to have such a strong IT com unity! Have a nice week!

Answer (score 1):

Building on @ChrisProsser's answer, this will take the date and:

- Calculate the interval between the dates in the current row and immediately preceding row (as ordered by ascending date) using the `LAG` analytical function; then
- Format that difference as a `HH:MI:SS` string.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfb67/13)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
create table some_table (ID_DAY number(8), ID_HOUR number(6));
insert into some_table values (20130912, 0);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 1);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 94511);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 104237);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 105145);
insert into some_table values (20130912, 105211);
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT id_day,
         id_hour,
         to_date(id_day||lpad(id_hour, 6, 0), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') date_value
  FROM some_table
  ORDER BY date_value
),
intervals AS (
  SELECT id_day,
         id_hour,
         date_value,
         (date_value - LAG( date_value ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_value )) DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) AS diff
  FROM   dates
  ORDER BY date_value
)
SELECT id_day,
       id_hour,
       date_value,
       CASE WHEN diff IS NULL THEN NULL
            ELSE LPAD( EXTRACT( HOUR FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
                    || ':' || LPAD( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
                    || ':' || LPAD( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
            END AS "difference"
FROM   intervals
ORDER BY date_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfb67/13/0)**:

```
|   ID_DAY | ID_HOUR |                       DATE_VALUE | DIFFERENCE |
|----------|---------|----------------------------------|------------|
| 20130912 |       0 | September, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     (null) |
| 20130912 |       1 | September, 12 2013 00:00:01+0000 |   00:00:01 |
| 20130912 |   94511 | September, 12 2013 09:45:11+0000 |   09:45:10 |
| 20130912 |  104237 | September, 12 2013 10:42:37+0000 |   00:57:26 |
| 20130912 |  105145 | September, 12 2013 10:51:45+0000 |   00:09:08 |
| 20130912 |  105211 | September, 12 2013 10:52:11+0000 |   00:00:26 |
```

**Query 2**:

Or reformatted to the string you were requesting:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT id_day,
         id_hour,
         to_date(id_day||lpad(id_hour, 6, 0), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') date_value
  FROM some_table
  ORDER BY date_value
),
intervals AS (
  SELECT id_day,
         id_hour,
         date_value,
         LAG( date_value ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_value ) AS previous_date_value,
         (date_value - LAG( date_value ) OVER ( ORDER BY date_value )) DAY(0) TO SECOND(0) AS diff
  FROM   dates
  ORDER BY date_value
)
SELECT 'From '
        || TO_CHAR( previous_date_value, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' )
        || ' to '
        || TO_CHAR( date_value, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS' )
        || ' passed '
        || LPAD( EXTRACT( HOUR FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
        || ':' || LPAD( EXTRACT( MINUTE FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
        || ':' || LPAD( EXTRACT( SECOND FROM diff ), 2, '0' )
        AS formatted_output
FROM   intervals
WHERE  previous_date_value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY date_value
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfb67/13/1)**:

```
|                                                FORMATTED_OUTPUT |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| From 2013/09/12 00:00:00 to 2013/09/12 00:00:01 passed 00:00:01 |
| From 2013/09/12 00:00:01 to 2013/09/12 09:45:11 passed 09:45:10 |
| From 2013/09/12 09:45:11 to 2013/09/12 10:42:37 passed 00:57:26 |
| From 2013/09/12 10:42:37 to 2013/09/12 10:51:45 passed 00:09:08 |
| From 2013/09/12 10:51:45 to 2013/09/12 10:52:11 passed 00:00:26 |
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Always nice to have a second opinion!